# Set a proxy individually for each WebBrowser?

Tags: .net, proxy, browser

I just found out [how to change proxies without restarting the WebBrowser control](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet/InternetSetOption.html?diff=y), but that seems to set it for ALL `WebBrowser` controls on my form. I want to be able to set a different proxy for each control. Is this possible?

If not, is there any tricks I can do to get around this? Maybe some kind of daemon that watches a port and translates that request into a proxy request? For example:

```
Request on port 12345 -> Connect to url on port 80, but use proxy 1.2.3.4:8080
Request on port 12346 -> Connect to url on port 80, but use proxy 6.4.5.1:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

In our application we resolved this launching every browser in a separate process and reparenting it. 
We don't reach to set a proxy for all webbrowser in the same process.